QEMU compilation hanging unexpectedly
I'm using QEMU 8.1.2 and I've done some modifications to the code. When I compile, it does not show any errors, but hangs at a certain instance without completing the compilation.
SS of compilation hanging
What could be the reason for this? I have tried with several servers and this is not a resource issue
A qemu code compilation problem and a possible answer how to fix it

I've done some modifications to the code what modifications? When I compile how do you compile exactly? it does not show any errors, what is "it"? Please post all full verbatim messages you are receiving and all full commands that you are executing. Please do not images of text or links to images of text - please post text as text into the question. And you might get more help from qemu developers https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/qemu-devel .

Some obvious things: (1) check that it builds OK without any of your changes in it. (2) make sure it really is hanging, and not just taking a while over a particular compilation step -- that "generating docs" step is not very fast.
